# How to hide activity view inside fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I am newbie in android development and trying to develop simple news application. But I've got a problem when using fragments.

This my activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include layout="@layout/app_container_view"/>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_container_ view xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id = "@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

toolbar xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
   app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
   app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="EastNews"
    style="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

When i replace fragments with transaction it only changes toolbar in fragment and rest inherits from activity view. I don't want to activity tabs and other views become visible on fragment UI.

fragment xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<!-- <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerIraq"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> -->
```

I've replaced fragment in this way

```
 boolean fragmentPopped = fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(fragment.getClass().getName(),0);

    if(!fragmentPopped && fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragment.getClass().getName()) == null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().getName());
        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName());
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Thanks to Rahul problem has been solved. Before posting question i've tried to solve this by adding setVisibility(View.GONE) to attach() and setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) to detach() method. It worked too but activity view loaded slowly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your parent **RelativeLayout** of **fragment.xml** add below 2 lines as:

```
android:background="@color/white"
android:clickable="true"
```

background color is whatever your fragment background color. This way you will be not able to see activity views when you have fragment opened. Hope it will help you out.

Comment: woow this worked. Is it  hides view of activity or what? I mean if i add some content to fragment it will work properly?

Comment: yes, it will work properly. Please vote my answer if it help you out.

Comment: I've just wanted to be sure about fragment content. Thank you very much.